# How to see parameter values of custom events for specific dates in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I created a custom event which returns a parameter value in GA4. The custom event is called *HP_StayTime*, and as the name suggests, it measures how much time the user stays on the Home Page screen of my app.  It is fired each time the user navigates in and subsequently away from the Home Page.

However, I am only able to see the parameter value for *HP_StayTime* for the last 30 minutes, and not for any specific date range, as it can be seen in the following screenshot.

*[HP_StayTime Event Engagement Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoMYJ.png)*

If you look at the screenshot, the *Event Value* tab also shows 0, while the *Event Count, Total Users, Event Count Per User tabs* have values. I am not sure why this is, even though some values are being shown in the last 30 mins widget.

I have already tried going through the other tabs of GA4 to find *HP_StayTime*'s parameter value, including the exploration tab, but the parameter value always shows 0.

I really need to find out how long users are staying in my home page over the last two weeks, and any help would be appreciated!